# Entity framework core, Keyword not supported: 'server:(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;database'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using .net 6 and EntityFrameworkCore Version 6.0.8. I made a migration and tried to update database with updata-database command in Package manager console but the following exception is thrown:
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server:(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;database'.
This is my connection string in the appsettings file:
"Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Bulky;Trusted_Connection=True;"
[image]

and this is my program.cs file:
[image]

What might be the problem?

Comment: Server is used when database (mdf file) is attached to database and localdB is used when database (mdf file) is not attached to server.  Never use both Server and Localdb.  See following for examples of connection strings.  Some may not be correct (have both server and localdb) : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @jdweng  "Server" is an alias for "Data Source" and is always used.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft : You may be right, but that is confusing.  Sever should be used when database is attached to server and Data Source when the file is not attached.

Comment: It's clearly documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, the connection string returned from your configuration is messed up, and looks something like

"server:(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;database= . . ."

Which parses all of `server:(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;database` as a single Keyword.

.NET Core configuration can load from multiple locations, so your appSettings.json may not be the source of the configuration value.

Comment: Yes thank you. I found another .json file where the connection string was messed up.